# I need to optimize a website and I want it to import the js libraries only when I need themL

Tags: javascript, optimization

My problem is that I need to optimize a website, one of the ways is by removing that JS that is not used in the page, the website is quite large, I have managed to remove that JS that is not used but I need the JS libraries that are not used do not load them, that is, only load them when you need them, is there a way to load it when you are going to use it.

I have no knowledge of classes or ID

Comment: Where do these JS libraries come from - from plugins, or your theme, or core WordPress? What do they do? Are they for things like shortcodes or widgets that are not used on every page, but are used on some specific pages?

Comment: They are external libraries that I use in some specific pages, like the slider, swiper, select2 library

Comment: You'll need to identify those specific pages and then you can enqueue them only on those pages.

Comment: There are too many pages to go looking where each bookstore is